# Line wrapping issues in xterm

Tags: php, bash, word-wrap, xterm, ansi-escape

I am writing a program that prints colored lines, and the more I do with it the more I find myself working around line wrapping issues that come up.

It is a sort of terminal written in php, here is the prompt:

```
$return = readline("\033[44m\033[1;37m{$this->text}>>\033[0m ");
```

and scrolling through history, the non-printing characters play havoc on everything.

If I try to add escapes

```
$return = readline("\[\033[44m\033[1;37m\]{$this->text}>>\[\033[0m\] ");
```

then it prints the brackets...even if I add double backslashes.

```
\[\][timer]>>\[\]
```

I find the same thing for echo -e, I am really not sure whats going on.

Lastly, if I modify PS1 it works just fine.

```
[mike@crest ~]$ export PS1="\[\033[44m\033[1;37m\][timer]>>\[\033[0m\] "
[timer]>>
```

What am I missing here?

Edit: the coloring/display is not the problem. The problem is that bash will have line wrapping issues when invisible characters are printed without escapes...and when I add the escapes they are printed in plain text under all circumstances but PS1, and I'm not sure what the difference is, how to get it working in PHP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cygwin wraps text back on to the same line, causing text to be overwritten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697195/cygwin-wraps-text-back-on-to-the-same-line-causing-text-to-be-overwritten)

Comment: bash interprets the `\[` and `\]` specially for `PS1`, and those are not recognized by anything else -- including a terminal emulator.

Answer (score 0):

php 1.php

[TIMER]>>

```
<?php

$return = readline("\033[44m\033[1;37m[TIMER]>>\033[0m ");

?>
```

Here is dialog example added

```
dialog --title "Welcome" --msgbox "\nMY TEST DIALOG \n\nPress <Enter> to continue or <Esc> to cancel." 10 50
```

Comment: Unfortunately the problem I am having is not a coloring or printing issue, but a line wrapping issue. If I scroll through history, the prompt becomes 11 characters off. If I type 21 characters and then press backspace, it begins deleting the previous line. This is on a console that is 57 columns wide.

Comment: I think I understand the issue, to be honest using colours even in a shell script, once the line hits the end of console width a new line with the colour set from above is generated. Have you though of using dialog I am sure it would work through php script too

Comment: That is not the issue either. Colors are just fine. the issue is scrolling through history, the text gets misaligned. For instance, if I run 'list', then 'checkin', then scroll up twice, this is what I get: [timer]>> checkin         list (thats ten spaces in between) and scrolling down gets me [timer]>> checkin         checkin