# Cygwin wraps text back on to the same line, causing text to be overwritten

Tags: bash, cygwin, xterm

I have cygwin installed on my Windows 7 box and I have been running into a problem where **when I type a command it will occasionally be wrapped back onto the same line, deleting the bash prompt.** Here is an example:

[image: wrapping example]

The command in question is command "201" (4 lines from the bottom). I included the others for context.

The text of the command I was typing was

`git commit -m "Forced LF line endings."`

(*Note: I am posting this with mostly git commands, but the problem occurs with any command. I have not noticed a pattern yet.*)

It jumped to the **start of the line** and started to overwrite my prompt.

When I push the up arrow (to view the history) the result is even weirder:

[image]

*(Note the cursor is many characters past the end of the command.)*
When I try to backspace the cursor from that position, I can only go back this far:

[image]

Then when I go up into the history from that backspaced line, I get this:

[image]

**The command starts from the end of the text that is displayed.** (This is consistent for the entire history) But when I go up in the history to the faulty `git commit ...` it displays as it did before with the overwritten text but when I go past it, **it deletes a line of the prompt** and displays the previous entry in the history the same way it was doing it before (a la image 2).

When I was creating my PS1 variable I has odd output like this, but I have since closed my brackets and things and don't think that is causing the issue. However if you would like to see my `.bash_profile` (that sets the PS1) feel free to see it on [GitHub](https://github.com/vidia/dotfiles/blob/master/.bash_profile). It is really short.

**I have tried searching for the issue and can only find a few cygwin email archives about the line wrapping in xterm, but no solutions.**

PS: As I was pushing the latest `.bash_profile`, in order to link it, I ran into the problem again when I typed `git add .bash_profile` and hit enter, it ran the command but **returned the cursor to the start of the same command instead of printing a new prompt**. 
Then when I as writing another commit line, it did the same as the first image, but **it blacked out the rest of the line** (It wrapped the line, but overwrote the entire line and not just the first few chars.)

Comment: I think this happens because you're not encoding the escape sequences in your prompt properly, so bash is confused about the amount of remaining space on the line.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How would I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc26:

> \[
>
> begin  a sequence of non-printing characters, which could be used to embed a terminal  control  sequence  into  the prompt
>
> \]
>
> end a sequence of non-printing characters

If you don't enclose non-printing characters (e.g. color sequences) in your prompt with these their length is counted as part of the prompt's length, eventually resulting in the symptoms that you describe.

Comment: I tested it on my new Mac's terminal and it seems to work fine. I am going to see if it is the same on other terminals as well, but for now, you get the accepted answer.



It seems the color codes need to start with `\e[` and then be closed with `\]`. My vim syntax highlighting did not match those as a pair so I added too many.

Comment: I ended up using bash's `$(tput setaf #)` to set the colors. It seems to work a lot better than the braces.

Comment: oh god, yes, I've had this problem for years and never knew why! (accidentally placed `\W` inside of `\[ ... \]`)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't occur frequently to me. When it does, I just type in 'kill -WINCH $$' into the cygwin terminal and it fixes the problem. [link to source](http://superchlorine.com/2013/08/kill-winch-to-fix-bash-prompt-wrapping-to-the-same-line/)